# How to count no of data types in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

How many variables are of type 'factor' in the dataset ?

```
> str(bollywood)

'data.frame':   52 obs. of  8 variables:
 $ Movie       : chr  "Dilwale" "Bajirao Mastani" "Hate Story 3" "Tamasha" ...
 $ Hero        : Factor w/ 39 levels "Abhishek_Bachchan",..: 38 30 36 28 34  29 31 20 35 19 ...
 $ Rdate       : Factor w/ 42 levels "01-05-2015","02-10-2015",..: 26 26 5 37 16 41 41 41 32 22 ...
 $ Ocollection : num  21 12.8 9.72 10.94 40.35 ...
 $ Wcollection : num  65.1 46.8 26.8 38.2 129.8 ...
 $ Fwcollection: num  102.7 86.2 42.2 53.5 172.8 ...
 $ Tcollection : num  148.7 184.2 51.7 67.3 210.2 ...
 $ Verdict     : Factor w/ 4 levels "Average","Flop",..: 3 3 4 1 3 2 2 2 2 4 ...
```

I can see manually that there are 4 factors in the data frame.Is there a way I can get a count of factors ? I want to count no of data types in a data frame

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Or more generally, to count the number of each type, you could use

```
table(sapply(bollywood, class))
```

this will print a table with the count of each data type for the entire data.frame.

Answer (score 4):

As the OP's question is about a specific class,  we can loop through the columns with `sapply`, check whether it is a `factor` and `sum` the logical vector.

```
sum(sapply(bollywood, is.factor))
```

Or another option is `grepl`

```
sum(grepl("Factor",capture.output(str(bollywood))))
```

#### Update

If the OP wants to check both `character` and `factor` columns

```
sum(sapply(bollywood, function(x) is.factor(x)|is.character(x)))
```

A faster `general` approach is

```
table(vapply(bollywood, class, ''))
```